# Tab panel and card layout in Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

In my application's main layout there will be three main panels, two regular panels with dynamic content and one tab panel.
Tab panel without being part of card layout working fine, but when I do something like this, tab panel becomes broken (tabs are not switching and"  tabBarPosition: 'bottom' " being ignored :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

mainPanel = Ext.create("Ext.Panel", {
    iconCls : 'info',
    title : 'Info',
    html : 'this is info panel'
});
contentPanel = Ext.create("Ext.Panel", {
    iconCls : 'more',
    title : 'About Us',
    html : 'this is about panel'
});
statisticsPanel = Ext.create("Ext.tab.Panel", {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    items: [
            {
                title: 'Home',
                iconCls: 'home',
                html: 'Home Screen'
            },
            {
                title: 'Contact',
                iconCls: 'user',
                html: 'Contact Screen'
            }
        ]       
});


function onLoad() {
    Ext.create("Ext.Panel", {
        fullscreen : true,
        layout : 'card',
        items : [ mainPanel,contentPanel, statisticsPanel ]
    }).setActiveItem(0);
}

Ext.application({
    name : 'Sencha',
    launch : function() {
        onLoad();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to instantiate a TabPanel instead of Panel, like this:

```
Ext.create("Ext.TabPanel", {
    fullscreen : true,
    items : [ mainPanel,contentPanel, statisticsPanel ]
}).setActiveItem(0);
```